# Do spaces get more similar as the number of dimensions increase?

Tags: geometry

Disclaimer: Non-mathematician, so my terminology may not be right.

Maryna Viazovska is one of the [2022 Fields Medal winners](https://www.mathunion.org/imu-awards/fields-medal/fields-medals-2022) for her work on [sphere packing in 8 and 24 dimensional spaces](https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/IMU/Prizes/Fields/2022/MV_FM.pdf). This made me wonder if packing in (say) 24 dimensions was somehow dramatically different to packing in 25, or 23 dimensions and if so, why?

It seems reasonable that the behaviour of 1 dimensional space would be very different to 2 dimensional spaces (you have twice as many dimensions!), and 3d spaces would be quite different to 2d spaces with 50% more dimensions to play with. But is there a large  difference between the geometry of 23 and 24 dimensional spaces? Or between 23463466 & 23463467 dimensional spaces? Is there a number of dimensions above which the geometrical differences of those spaces becomes insignificant?

Comment: Well, the gap between 8 and 24 seems to suggest that's not something monotonically increasing. But I may be wrong, naturally, as my intuition tends to break down in 4 dimensions, already. Oh, and I *am* a mathematician.

Comment: An interesting fact:   if you consider the formula for the volume of an $n$-dimensional sphere,  it goes to zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: To make @Cpc's observation more intuitive, note that it's easy to see that the *distance from the origin to a corner of the unit cube* goes to infinite as the dimension goes to infinity. Now think about a sphere sitting inside a cube ...

Comment: I have a feeling that the spaces get **more different** per unit increase in dimension as the dimension increases, but due to our $3$-dimensional cognitive limitations **[1]**, we are blind to virtually everything nontrivial in higher dimensions. $[\,$ **[1]** At present, at least. Our post-human descendants, as described in Greg Egan's 1995 short story "Wang's carpets" (who are able to fully visualize spaces of at least $16$ dimensions), will no doubt be quite a bit less blind than we are regarding phenomena in dimensions from $4$ to $20$ or so$.]$

Comment: @Noah Schweber: My gut feeling for why I think the spaces get more different per unit dimension increase (previous comment) is that the situation is probably analogous to the Ackermann function hierarchy -- addition (1), multiplication (2), exponentiation (3), tetration (4), etc. -- in which the "increase in growth rate" from each level to the next level overshadows the type of increases in prior levels. While we have an intuitive grasp of this phenomena at the lower levels (this [8 April 2002 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/8M-Q8Cp715M/m/8nJbOODYLk8J) **(continued)**

Comment: can be considered an attempt to study this at the 4th and 5th levels), fully conceptualizing this for the increase from level $477$ to level $478,$ or from level $5{\omega}^2 + 66{\omega} + 2{\omega} + \omega + 25$ to level $5{\omega}^2 + 66{\omega} + 2{\omega} + \omega + 26,$ or from level $\epsilon_0 + 7$ to level $\epsilon_0 + 8$ is a totally different situation. I strongly suspect the per-dimension increase in "interesting phenomena" as the dimension increases is similar, as well as our inability to conceptualize in any nontrivial way these "interesting phenomena".

Comment: The special thing about dimension 24 is the existence of the [Leech lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_lattice), which provides the optimal packing. There are no similar lattices in dimensions 23, 25 and, as far as I know, nobody has a conjecture what the optimal packing in these dimensions will be.